# How can an Image be centered the same in Lauchscreen and View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to have the Lauchscreen and the first view look the same, only the first view should have an activity spinner on it, the transition shouldn't be visible. There's only one image in the center. However, **during the transition from Lauchscreen to View there is an offset**.

### [In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBUuM.png) the overlap is visible.

### View:

```
struct SessionPendingView: View {
    var body: some View {
    
        ZStack {
            Image("Signet")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 128, height: 128, alignment: .center)
            ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large)
                .padding(.top, 200)
        }

    }   
}
```

### [Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgNpx.png)

---

I thought it might be because one screen is centered on the safe area while the other is not, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Edit: Same issue on the iPhone SE, so not a safe area problem

I created a small project that has the issue, you can download it [here](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0QPAmgpv-r-OWbPKdrWXLRObQ#LauchVisualTest)

Comment: In the LaunchScreen.storyboard, I removed the leading and top constraints and replaced them with setting the width and height of the image to 200 and 70. I also changed the centerX and centerY constraints to use the Safe Area instead of the Superview.  This works well for all iPhones except the iPhone 11 which still seems to shift slightly.  Perhaps you should add the 2x and 3x assets for your image.

Comment: As you said, it's sadly still there on iPhone X and higher

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
    ZStack {
        Image("Signet")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 128, height: 128, alignment: .center)
        ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)     // << this !!
```

Comment: I actually tried that before and just ran it an iPhone without a notch - didn't solve it. So it's sadly not a safe area problem... Thank's for the suggestion though :)

Comment: Try updated variant - removed also unneeded padding & added max frame.

Comment: Sadly doesn't change anything. I uploaded a project containing the issue [here](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0QPAmgpv-r-OWbPKdrWXLRObQ#LauchVisualTest), it'd be nice if you could have a look .